# What is the parameter _config["StoredFilesPath"] and where should it be located

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET core 3 and C# development so I'm not sure what or where this variable *should* be located. Is this something that *should* go in `Startup.cs`?

```
foreach (var formFile in files)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(_config["StoredFilesPath"],   <-- This "_config[....]"
            Path.GetRandomFileName());

        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the documentation that I'm following 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Despite being in the "advanced" section I am still a newb.

Comment: Usually that value goes into appsettings.json file.  Refer this link for configuration management https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Are you asking where the value for `"StoredFilesPath"` should go (that's what the existing answers address) or are you asking where the code you've shown here should go?

Comment: @NoU I'm pretty sure it should go in my controller class but I cannot figure out where that `_config` is coming from. I would assume it's a private variable of the class but then I cannot get `config.GetValue<string>("StoredFilesPath");` to work in that case. I'm currently trying to figure out how to call the non-default constructor of this controller class so that I have access to the `IConfiguration config` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Startup.cs` is a good place for the code that reads the config.

ASP.NET can inject dependencies into the constructors of your controllers if you tell it how to create those dependencies in `Startup.cs`. First you need to give `Startup` a constructor with a dependency so the config gets injected:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

So that's where it comes from. The framework knows how to create it for you.

For ease of maintainability, I prefer not to inject the `IConfiguration` itself into controllers. I read all the config settings in `Startup.cs` and use them to construct higher level things. For example, in one project I'm working on, I have this method in `Startup.cs`:

```
private EmailService EmailService()
{
    var host = Configuration["Smtp:Host"];
    var user = Configuration["Smtp:User"];
    var pass = Configuration["Smtp:Password"];
    var name = Configuration["Smtp:SenderName"];
    var address = Configuration["Smtp:SenderAddress"];
    var debug = Configuration["Smtp:DebugRecipients"];
    return new EmailService(host, user, pass, name, address, debug);
}
```

Then in the `ConfigureServices` method, I construct the `EmailService` and add it to the service collection:

```
    services.AddSingleton(EmailService());
```

Comment: After doing further reading on ASP.NETs Dependency Injection, after you mentioned it, I finally figured it out. I'll add that I'm not sure where you were going with the Service stuff but I was able to work with it in a Controller context. It seems I had everything accept that I needed to simply add `_config = config` inside of my controller class constructor. Not `config.GetValue<string>("StoredFilesPath");`

Comment: @luckyging3r Moving most of your logic to services helps keep controllers thin. Controllers should basically just control who can access what. Services do all the real work.

Comment: Ahhh I see, I'll look into that next. 

Comment: If you did use config to hardcode file path how would you create a file path in appsettings.json that works on both your local system and your development system since the absolute paths would like differ.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to initialize the path as below in your **appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Warning"
    }
 },
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"StoredFilesPath": "c:\\files",
"FileSizeLimit": 2097152
}
```

then add your setting via startup.cs like

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually that value goes into appsettings.json file.

Refer [configuration management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 0):

As Sai Puli states, you need to set that as a key in your application configuration.  In traditional .NET this would be handled in a `web.config` or `app.config` file.